# Is it allowable to use different AQL sampling plan/level for large lot size

Tags: aql, inspection, industrial

I just joined this new company, and I noticed they used different AQL plan/level for certain range of lot size for their Incoming Quality Control inspections. Eg: (2-1200 pieces = 0.40 AQL Plan, 1201 and above = 0.10 AQL Plan). They use SPECIAL INSPECTION LEVEL S-2 and the lot size are usually around 800 to 14000 per delivery. And in their defense is that they don't have designated IQC inspection area to perform a high quantity and long period of time for inspection.

I really hope you guys can come up with an answer if we are allowed to use different AQL plan for larger lot quantity.

I'm seeking for answer regarding my questions so that I can at least point out that the system they are currenty on is false and could maybe lead to a room for improvements